# where to download jsapar - I cannot find the download section or update link

Tags: collabnet, jsapar

The jsapar.tigris.org site seems to be very different; I just cannot find a way to download the jsapar jar; is also not available in any of the maven repositories. any help for the download link will help. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I added a link to the front page to make it more obvious.

Any day I will add it to a maven repository as well, but for the time beeing you have to install it your self in your local repository. There is a maven pom file within the project so you should be able to build it with maven locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like they are posting releases in the "Documents and Files" section of the project.  See here:

http://jsapar.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=11435

Looks like they offer a zip with the JAR and JavaDoc included and another with the source code.

Update 2019: binaries are found in the Maven repository automatically. For code, you can visit their website at GitHub at the following address:

https://github.com/org-tigris-jsapar/jsapar

Answer (score 0):

As of 1.5.0 version of the library has now finally been published to the maven central repository.
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.tigris.jsapar%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jsapar%22

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.tigris.jsapar</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsapar</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

EDIT: The project has moved from tigris.org to github.com, see their website here:
https://github.com/org-tigris-jsapar/jsapar